# How to use computer's Bluetooth to send Wallpapers to any cellphone, in C#?

Tags: c#, bluetooth

I'd like to know if it is possible how to do it, because my client asked me if the program I'm developing could also send wallpapers to nearby cellphones(my program will be in a place with many people passing by, so it would be good to have the bluetooth feature).
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it can send pictures as files, users then may set them as wallpapers.

Comment: 1) Only if the phone supports file transfer over bluetooth, which many don't, and 2) only if the user connects their phone to the host computer. It really sounds like the "client" wants to push ads over bluetooth to nearby phones which is not possible (thank goodness).

Comment: Well, It's more like the client wanting to offer things to nearby phones, like free wallpapers, free songs, etc... Sure it would be annoying to have a bluetooth spammer.

Comment: my answer plus first comment describe maximum you can get.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the phone and the computer support bluetooth and are connected, you cannot. You can send the files to mobiles over bluetooth. 32feet provides a nice library to perform bluetooh related operations. Try that.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you would need to

1. Make sure each user's device is paired to your bluetooth "sever"
2. Create the ability to auto connect and send the file.
3. On your phone's application, receive the image file and set the phone background - this will be different for each type of phone's OS. I would assume you are aiming towards Window Mobile Devices, since you are using c#.

The first step i see as being the difficult step as each phone much "register" the bluetooth of the server to be paired with it.